# Diamond shaped button with border

Tags: flutter, dart

anyone know how to design this button in flutter? It's a diamond shaped button with a border color.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

result

[image]
[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DimondButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const DimondButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Transform(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
            math.pi / 4,
          ),
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              border: Border.all(
                width: 3,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
            ),
            child: InkWell(
              splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              onTap: () {},
              child: Center(
                child: Transform(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                    -math.pi / 4,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    "Click",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i've finished the code, and its exactly the same with this. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

you have multiple approaches
you can create a container with border color and transparent inner and transform it using `transform.translate`
the other one is using custom paint which is a bit harder

Comment: Don't you mean `Transform.rotate`?

Comment: cool, thanks! i've tried around, and its okay i think

Comment: Hi, do you know how anyway to change Ink's effect color? @Ardeshir ojan

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use below code, add this dependency to your pubspec.yaml file  **flutter_custom_clippers: ^1.1.2**  [package found here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers/versions/1.1.2)

```
          ClipPath(
            clipper: ParallelogramClipper(),
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              color: Colors.pinkAccent,
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print('object');
                },
                child: Text('OK'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```